# Merging preg_match_all and preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have some code running which finds out hashtags in the string and turns them into links. I have done this using `preg_match_all` as shown below:

```
if(preg_match_all('/(#[A-z_]\w+)/', $postLong, $arrHashTags) > 0){
foreach ($arrHashTags[1] as $strHashTag) {
  $long = str_replace($strHashTag, '<a href="#" class="hashLinks">'.$strHashTag.'</a>', $postLong);

    }   
}
```

Also, for my search script, I need to bold the searched keywords in the result string. Something similar to the below code using `preg_replace`:

```
$string = "This is description for Search Demo";
$searchingFor = "/" . $searchQuery . "/i";
$replacePattern = "<b>$0<\/b>";
preg_replace($searchingFor, $replacePattern, $string);
```

The problem that I am having is that both have to work together and should be thrown as a **combined result**. One way I can think of is to run the resultant string from `preg_match_all` with the `preg_replace` code but what if the tags and the searched string are the same? The second block will bold my tag as well which is not desired.

**update** the code i'm running based on the answer given below but it still doesn't work

```
if(preg_match_all('/(#[A-z_]\w+)/', $postLong, $arrHashTags) > 0){
foreach ($arrHashTags[1] as $strHashTag) {
  $postLong = str_replace($strHashTag, '<a href="#" class="hashLinks">'.$strHashTag.'</a>', $postLong);

    }   
}
```

And immediately after this, i run this

```
 $searchingFor = "/\b.?(?<!#)" . $keystring . "\b/i";
 $replacePattern = "<b>$0<\/b>";
 preg_replace($searchingFor, $replacePattern, $postLong);
```

Just so you know, this is all going inside a `while` loop, which is generating the list

Comment: could anyone suggest something/

Comment: can you post the full while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify you the search pattern to avoid ones that start with a '#'

```
$postLong = "This is description for Search Demo";

if(preg_match_all('/(#[A-z_]\w+)/', $postLong, $arrHashTags) > 0){
  foreach ($arrHashTags[1] as $strHashTag) {
    $postLong = str_replace($strHashTag, '<a href="#" class="hashLinks">'.$strHashTag.'</a>', $postLong);
  }
}

#  This expression finds any text with 0 or 1 characters in front of it
# and then does a negative look-behind to make sure that the character isn't a #
searchingFor = "/\b.?(?<!#)" . $searchQuery . "\b/i";
$replacePattern = "<b>$0<\/b>";
preg_replace($searchingFor, $replacePattern, $postLong);
```

Or if you don't need an array of the available hashes for another reason, you could use preg_replace only.

```
$postLong = "This is description for #Search Demo";

$patterns = array('/(#[A-z_]\w+)/', "/\b.?(?<!#)" . $searchQuery . "\b/i");
$replacements = array('<a href="#" class="hashLinks">'.$0.'</a>', ' "<b>$0<\/b>');
preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $postLong);
```

Comment: then i'm pretty sure there is a workaround for it that you can think of

Comment: What if query is `"bla"` and string is `"#blabla"`?

Comment: @Jack good point, I added in `\b` word boundaries to prevent that.

Comment: @Jack its not working. i mean there are no errors being thrown too. I put it after the tag search code with `preg_match_all` that i gave above, but nothing happening

Comment: @coder101 can you add an updated version of the code you are running?